# Eliminating warnings from [binary.dup] step in pants.ini

Tags: pants

I am working on culling unnecessary output from the binary 'dup' step in my build.

When I run `./pants binary <target>` I have many instances of duplicates for `META-INF/services`:

```
Duplicate classes and/or resources detected in artifacts: ('com.sun.jersey-jersey-servlet-1.19.jar', 'net.kencochrane.raven-raven-6.0.0.jar', 'org.glassfish.web-javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar')
                        META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
```

There are many of these and they are expected.  The logic in creating a binary merges these services files together.

The format for `--binary-dup-exclude`s is a list of filenames without directories.    These all share a common directory prefix, but the filenames are different.  Is there a way to suppress these warnings in the dup step without listing each one individually?

Here is my current configuration:

```
[binary.dup]
excludes: [
    # Lots of crap from META-INF that gets duped.
    'dependencies','license','notice','.DS_Store','notice.txt','cmdline.arg.info.txt.1','license.txt',
    'readme.txt','README.txt','readme.md','BCKEY.DSA', 'BCKEY.SF', 'ASL2.0', 'about.html',
    'jersey-module-version', 'eclipse.inf', 'asm-license.txt',
    'pom.xml', 'pom.properties', 'INDEX.LIST',

    # We have many copies of env.yaml and app-manifest.yaml in the same place on the classpath
    'env.yaml', 'app-manifest.yaml',

    # com/sun/jersey/core/header/LanguageTag.class is intentionally overridden in service container to fix a bug in jersey
    'LanguageTag.class'
  ]
```

Comment: Well, it looks like I needed to add support for this:  https://rbcommons.com/s/twitter/r/3178/